# How to swap low resolution with high resolution textures dynamically and improve texture loading in general

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

In my ThreeJS project I want to swap out one texture with another but as soon as I do this the UV's are completely broken. You can see how I do it in the code below:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "T_Test_1k_BaseColor.jpg" );

function loadDraco6141012( src ) {
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath('');
    loader.setDRACOLoader( new THREE.DRACOLoader() );
    loader.load( src, function( gltf ) {
        gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child.isMesh ) {
                child.material.envMap = envMap;
                child.position.y -= 0.6
                mesh = child;

                // This needs to trigger only after the texture has fully loaded

                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    mesh.material.map = texture;
                }, 5000);

                // either way the uv doesn't seem to be correct anymore, what happened..?
            }
        } );
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
    }
}
```

You can see the whole thing in action here [www.dev.openstring-studios.com](https://www.dev.openstring-studios.com) As you can see there are several things very wrong with this example.

1. As said before the loading time is still pretty slow, how could this be improved? Would using a database like MySQL improve performance?
2. Why are th UV's broken, this looks horrible, what could be the problem? And just to be clear the green texture map is the same as the blue one, they are only different in color.

Here's the [ThreeJs Documentation / MeshStandardMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.map) about how applying maps should work. I cannot explain why it doesn't work out here. Why are the UV's suddenly broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't ask multiple questions in a single post, but I'll try:

1. You can improve loading times by drastically reducing the polygon count of your pot. Looking at the network tab in the dev tools, I noticed your `.gltf` is 3.67MB, which is unnecessarily large for a simple pot. You probably don't need this level of detail, you could remove 2/3rds the # of vertices, and your pot would still look good. 
   [image]

   - It also looks like you're exporting textures bundled in the GLTF, which is helping make your filesize that big. Maybe it's auto-exporting textures in really large sizes (4096x4096)? You should try exporting your textures separately, convert them to a compressed format (JPG), and make sure they're not unnecessarily large (1024x1024 could work). Then you can load them separately.
2. There is no way to load a texture in that way. You'd have to load them manually in incrementally larger sizes (256, 512, 1024, etc...). [TextureLoader has a callback](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader) that lets you know when the texture has been loaded.
3. UVs aren't broken, you're just loading a second texture that doesn't follow the same layout as the first texture. Make sure this image https://www.dev.openstring-studios.com/T_Test_1k_BaseColor.jpg follows the same layout as your original (green) texture.

Lastly, is there a reason why you separated the pot into 5 different meshes? Whenever possible, you should try making it just one mesh to reduce the number of WebGL drawcalls and get a bit of a performance boost.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but what are these pictures exactly? This does not look anything close to what can be seen on the website. There should be really only one central green pot and not like 5 different meshes - what are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, there is only one central pot. The images above were only to demonstrate the points I was trying to make. The wireframe was to show that your geometry is very dense, and could use less polygons to save space. The other image was just to demonstrate that there are 5 separate meshes, when they could be merged into a single one.

Comment: I still don't get it? Where are those 5 meshes hiding? I can always only see one mesh and as I've created the model myself I in fact know there should only be one mesh - what's going on here? Also what do you mean with the texture layouts aren't the same? The blue texture is the exact same texture map as the green one, just with a blue tint. My models need to be displayed in the highest quality possible, so no more poly count reduction and textures need to be 4k, at least at the end. Look at sketchfab.com, these are high-quality models there, I need to be able to keep up with that.

Comment: Well, you asked for suggestions on how to speed up download times, I gave you commonly-used optimization methods. That's all I got to offer. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well yes, I didn't mean to say that your suggestions weren't helpful. It's the thing with the 5 Meshes and the not working UV's which is where I need help..

Comment: If you don't want to answer it's okay. Obviously there is something seriously wrong with my export / import pipeline - I'll troubleshoot that myself and come back with another question if really needed. Thanks for your help!